# Верстка с использованием бутстрап по psd макету

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

По [ссылке](http://joxi.ru/zANnkg5ilQEkPA0) изображен макет.

- Контентная часть (3) составляет по макету `1008 px`.
- Отступы (1,2)
  составляют `81 px`.
- Ширина между крайними линиями нарисованной сетки
  в макете (4) `1170 px` (хотя там нет контента кроме звезд).

Подскажите как лучше верстать (имею ввиду блок контента в котором будут располагаться все остальные блоки):

1. Использовать блок `bootstrap container` (`1170px`) и выставить отступы `margin-left- right 81 px`.
2. Задать ширину в `1008 px` без отступов. С учетом того что макет для мобильных версий контентная часть, тоже не попадает  в размер bootstrap container и составляет `667 px`.

Comment: берете бутстрэп 4, в sass задаете свои переменные ширин и кажется это ответ на все 4 вопроса.

Comment: ссылка на макет битая,

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev, напишите в ответ, поддерживаю

Answer (score 1):

Стоит использовать `scss` версию `bootstrap 4`, добавлям ее в `package.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        "bootstrap": "4.1.1",
        "popper.js": "1.14.3",
        "jquery": "3.3.*"
    }
}
```

Устанавливаем зависимости - `npm install`

Создаем главный `scss` файл с подключением бутстрепа и назначением переменных:

```
$container-max-widths: (
    sm: 540px,
    md: 720px,
    lg: 960px,
    xl: 1008px
);
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Все переменные, которые можно перезаписать можно посмотреть здесь:
`node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss`

Дальше собираем все сборщиком (gulp/webpack или консольным scss)

Comment: Скидываю ссылку с макетом http://joxi.ru/krD6B73U0P0lX2

Comment: что без использования препроцессора , уже вообще никто не верстатет ? А если нужно верстать а технологию я не знаю?

Comment: Если допустим нужно изменить вид готового сайта править только стиль можно это будет организовать с помощью препроцессора ?

Comment: @ЯковБалакирев, без препроцессора это геморой, вы можете перезаписать media запросы переписав в них ширину контейнера. Освоить не сложно, всего пару шагов, которые я написал в ответе. А "править можно только стиль" это какой-то странный комментарий, ну правьте только стиль.